# Tomcat suddenly shutdown

Tags: tomcat7, 503-error, shutdown

Tomcat randomly stops receiving requests and returns error 503.

Im running a tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 TLS updated.

In the apache error log you can see the following trace:

```
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[Wed Mar 04 09:36:27 2015] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
```

There is no trace of error in any of the tomcat log files (catalina) :S

That is not caused by memory leaks Head Space or Java Head Space, because i cause these problems and error traces appear in the log files (besides, I reviewed the code and there is no system.exit() on any file :P).

I'm pretty confused and i can't understand what is happening, thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure your system has not been restarted.

Comment: I'm sure it has not been restarted, I have to restart it manually to get it working again.